# Append Shapley reason codes on all observations to the entire data

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Here is my code to get the top 5 Shaply reason codes on mtcars dataset.

```
#install.packages("randomForest"); install.packages("tidyverse"); install.packages(""iml)
library(tidyverse); library(iml); library(randomForest) 

set.seed(42)

mtcars1 <- mtcars %>%  mutate(vs = as.factor(vs),
                              id = row_number())

x <- "vs"
y <- paste0(setdiff(setdiff(names(mtcars1), "vs"), "id"), collapse = "+")

rf = randomForest(as.formula(paste0(x, "~ ", y)), data = mtcars1, ntree = 50)

predictor = Predictor$new(rf, data = mtcars1, y = mtcars1$vs)


shapley = Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = mtcars1[1,])

shapleyresults <- as_tibble(shapley$results) %>% arrange(desc(phi)) %>% slice(1:5) %>% select(feature.value, phi)
```

1. How can I get the reason codes for all the observations (instead of one at a time in the 2nd last line in the above code: mtcars[1,])?
2. And, append/left_join the shapleyresults using id on to the entire dataset?

   The dataset would be 5-times longer. Should we use purrr here to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
#install.packages("randomForest"); install.packages("tidyverse"); install.packages("iml")
library(tidyverse); library(iml); library(randomForest) 

set.seed(42)

mtcars1 <- mtcars %>%  mutate(vs = as.factor(vs),
                              id = row_number())

x <- "vs"
y <- paste0(setdiff(setdiff(names(mtcars1), "vs"), "id"), collapse = "+")

rf = randomForest(as.formula(paste0(x, "~ ", y)), data = mtcars1, ntree = 50)

predictor <- Predictor$new(rf, data = mtcars1, y = mtcars1$vs)

shapelyresults <- map_dfr(1:nrow(mtcars), ~(Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = mtcars1[.x,]) %>% 
                                              .$results %>% 
                                              as_tibble() %>% 
                                              arrange(desc(phi)) %>% 
                                              slice(1:5) %>% 
                                              select(feature.value, phi) %>%
                                              mutate(id = .x)))

final_data <- mtcars1 %>% left_join(shapelyresults, by = "id")
```